# How to use the same GPU in GKE by multiple pods/containers?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia

I'd like to run an X.Org server and multiple desktop apps in GKE. Each in a separate container (probably each in separate pod). Ideally X.Org will be a DaemonSet to have a server on each node.

But here is just a test with a Pod that runs two containers: X.Org and an app:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: x11-socket
      hostPath:
        path: /tmp/x11-socket
  containers:
  - name: xserver
    image: xserver
    command: ["sleep"]
    args: ["infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: x11-socket
        mountPath: /tmp/.X11-unix
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 1
  - name: app
    image: app
    command: ["sleep"]
    args: ["infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: x11-socket
        mountPath: /tmp/.X11-unix
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 0
```

The pod overall declares that it needs 1 GPU so it gets it and it's even usable from inside of both containers.

The problem is that the NVIDIA driver files `/usr/local/nvidia/` appear only in the container that has `nvidia.com/gpu: 1`. If I copy the drivers to another container then `glxinfo` reports NVIDIA GPU there too.

How to make it put drivers in all containers just like the NVIDIA container runtime did when ran multiple Docker containers on a host?

Comment: Hi `Velkan` please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I've avoided using time-sharing GPUs on GKE. But then I've compared the performance of time-sharing with the performance of sharing that I've described in my question (setting up privileges and manually copying drivers): performance is the same.

I think that time-sharing doesn't do anything differently graphics-performance-wise. It just advertises to Kubernetes that there are more GPUs on the node than there really are.

Note: to get time-sharing when creating a node pool for example with the command `gcloud container node-pools create` append `gpu-sharing-strategy=time-sharing,max-shared-clients-per-gpu=8` to the `--accelerator` option.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **[NVIDIA Container Runtime](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-container-runtime)** for deploying your containers it has an in-built functionality for deploying your containers along with the **NVIDIA gpu drivers** or **plugins** that are required by your GPU-Accelerated applications. Similarly in google cloud if you want to **[configure gpu to your pods or containers](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#pods_gpus)** you need to mention following **key-value pair**

- Key: [nvidia.com/gpu](http://nvidia.com/gpu)
- Value: Number of GPUs to consume (Which you have defined for XOrg server)

When you mention the above **key-value pair** GKE will deploy your pod along with the required NVIDIA drivers. You can also install them later by copying the binaries or running the required commands. However, it is not recommended because if your pods get recreated the newly created pod doesn’t contain these drivers, so it is suggested to use the above mentioned key-value pair or use a container image with built in **NVIDIA driver packages.**

If you want all your containers to have **NVIDIA support** either use a container image which contains the **NVIDIA plugins** or define the **key-value pair** in the pod specification.